# Mc Dojo warning signs…

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Would a community wiki be useful for warning signs of a Mc Dojo?

In general, I would close any such question as "asking for a list". However, in this particular case, it might be a good idea to have a generic question answered by a wiki entry that pointed to some warning signs…

The question could be phrases as such:

> What are the common warning signs that a dojo (or gym) be classed as a McDojo?

Comment: I like the idea but was wondering if there are any (closed?) questions that would be answered by refering to this proposed community wiki? In other words, how useful would it be?

Comment: @THelper: I do not think there are closed questions about this. I thought it might be one of those rare instances that a list of things might be really useful… Note that I did not start it before asking here because I would rather have everyone's agreement on it first.

Comment: I was [looking at our statistics](http://meta.martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/316/88) and the most important thing for graduation of MA SE seems to be the number of questions. So I propose to write the community wiki and we'll see how useful it is later.

Comment: @THelper: Shall you do it or should I?

Comment: Since it's community-wiki it doesn't matter much, but it's your idea so I'll let you write it.

Comment: [Question asked, wiki started…](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/6739/82)